# Establishing a TCP connection with async & await

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm not really super experienced async/await and working with tasks, so I thought I'd ask for some other opinions.

I'm working with code written by someone else that establishes a TCP connection. It works *most of the time*. But sometimes it just doesn't, and the connection gets dropped and we don't know about it.

My first suspicion is that it's calling `Task.Run(() =>`, which goes on to call a method that calls `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>`, which in turn goes to call `await Task.Run(() =>`.

Does this code look ok to more experienced eyes? Is there anything that could be done to improve it?

```
public bool StartListening(string ipAddress, int port)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _backingTcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);
        _backingTcpListener.Start();

        WaitForConnections(_canceller.Token);
    });

    return true;
}

private void WaitForConnections(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var inner = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return _backingTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    // this will be caused by StopListeningAsync
                    return null;
                }
            }, cancelToken);

            if (inner == null)
            {
                // null will be returned when the SocketException is caught above
                return;
            }

            var outer = new TcpSocketClient(inner, _bufferSize);

            var args = new TcpSocketConnectionReceivedEventArgs(outer);

            ConnectionReceived?.Invoke(args);
        }
    }, cancelToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```